# Reading Device Manager's Property Fields in Windows 7/8

Tags: windows, c#-4.0, windows-7, device-manager

I am developing a windows application which gives the field details --> X.

Where X is -->

Right Click My Computer  >

```
    Properties >

          Device Manager > (select any Item - Say KeyBoard) >

                   Click it > standard PS/2 KeyBoard >

                                double Click standard PS/2 KeyBoard >

                                           click the Details Tab >
```

Under the Property there are various fields like Display Name , Problem Code,Parent Siblings, etc , etc?

I want to get their values .
Which Windows API I can use for this.
I am doing this for windows 7 as well as windows 8.I hope the API will remain the same.Also i am having 64 bit machine.
This has to be true for any device whose details I wanted to know from the Device Manager.

ALso I just want to all  operations - Reading and No Set (writing) so I think I will not be having any problem with violating the Admin Rights.PLease suggest.! I have added Snapshots for reference!Say for example I want to know the current State of the HID USB Complaint Mouse(D0(Active) or D2(Sleep)).

[image: Image Showing the Powerdata Field for HID Compliant Mouse]

[image: Image Showing the Power State for HID Complaint Mouse That is D0 - Active]

I need to Get this Power State D0.

Answer (score 4):

The question is tagged with C#, though the actual question asks for any Window API. With the Win32 API the information can be retrieved with [SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551967%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The steps would be:

1. Get a device info set for the devices you're interested in via [SetupDiGetClassDevs()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
2. Iterate through the device infos via [SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551010%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
3. Get the properties via calls to SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty().
4. Destroy the device info set via [SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550996%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

According to the documentation the API is available on Windows 2000 and later.

Comment: This is the correct answer. To find the power state as requested in the question you need to query SPDRP_DEVICE_POWER_DATA using SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite easy to get the hardware information using  [ManagementObjectCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kedstsy5%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

For instance to get all properties and values from the PC processor

```
var win32DeviceClassName = "win32_processor";
            var query = string.Format("select * from {0}", win32DeviceClassName);

            using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query))
            {
                ManagementObjectCollection  objectCollection = searcher.Get();

                foreach (ManagementBaseObject managementBaseObject in objectCollection)
                {
                    foreach (PropertyData propertyData in managementBaseObject.Properties)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Property:  {0}, Value: {1}", propertyData.Name, propertyData.Value);
                    }
                }



            }
```

The full list of WIN32 class name is available at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394084%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Cheers.

Comment: I am runnning x64 , still I have to use the string "var win32DeviceClassName = "win32_processor";"

Comment: The code snippet here is supposed to do what you asked. Yes, copy it to the main function of your C# console project. It will enumerate all properties of your processor.

Comment: Do you know why I get a type mismatch when trying to set a DateTime object to the "InstallDate" property?

Comment: While WMI objects have some of the same info, they don't provide a way to query all of the properties shown in the Device Manager that I can find (as per the question asked).

Comment: I did - WMI simply doesn't give you access to all the same state that is available in the device manager. The answer listed using SetupDiGetClassDevs & SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty is the correct answer. All the state items shown in Device Manager are available using SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have the easiest time (I think) doing this with PowerShell.  If you are writing some C# code you can execute a PS script using types in the System.Management.Automation namespace, such as PowerShell (link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.powershell(v=vs.85).aspx)  but I would begin your testing using the PS Console.

You should first (using PowerShell) explore the WMI objects in your environments using this command

```
Get-WmiObject -List -namespace root\CIMV2
```

Then once you identify with class you are looking for you can retrieve details on that class using this command:

```
Get-WmiObject -namespace root\CIMV2 -class Win32_USBControllerDevice
```

Once you have that content you'd have to parse the text.

**UPDATE:** Try using this command to get the "State", "Status", and "Started" attributes of mouse drivers on your PC:

```
gwmi Win32_SystemDriver | where {$_.DisplayName -like "*Mouse*"}
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I have improved the Question.What i Want is Quiet Different from What you propsed.With Power Shell I can get the Huge List of All USB Devices and thier properties whcih are not What I asked, I guess.PLease have a look at the snapshots for better clarity of the question.

Comment: With the correct query you can get that precise value.  I can refine my answer

Comment: Tha above command for Mouse doesnt gives the variable like " Power Data?

Comment: As with the other WMI answer, WMI doesn't give you access to all the same state.